Intermittent check engine limp mode hyundai accent 2015
I have an intermittent problem with my car, the car will enter into limp mode temporarily, the throttle wouldn't open till the end. The acceleration suddenly would decrease, I got two fault error codes:
P2127 and P0642

I changed the entire accelerator pedal but the issue remains, when I changed the throttle itself another throttle related error was shown.
I noticed that the pedal sensor E has low values when the problem is occuring:

What could be the other causes of the problem? Is it a throttle issue or an accelerating pedal issue?

Sounds like a wiring problem to me. The reference wire seems like it is getting compromised either by damaged wiring or a bad or dirty connector. Doing a jiggle test at the connectors for the reference wire could point you in the right direction.

I agree. The reference voltage (5v) may be faulty. triggering the intermittent limp home mode. 5V is used everywhere in EFI systems. Here are several links related to P0642;  https://www.obd-codes.com/p0642, https://www.carparts.com/blog/p0642-code-sensor-reference-voltage-a-circuit-low/, https://themotorguy.com/sensor-reference-voltage-troubles-what-p0642-means-for-your-vehicle/
